# Get a substring in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, substring

I am currently trying to implement and edit form in my application where the default values are the ones from the item which need to be adjusted. My database encrypts some values and adjusted them before storing. What I need is to get the substring of 5 digits between the `://` and `.` characters of the decrypted value. My form is formatted as:

```
{!! Form::hidden('id', Lang::get('token.id')); !!}
{!! Form::text('id', Crypt::decrypt($token->url), ['class' => 'form-control', 'maxlength' => 5, 'placeholder' => Lang::get('token.id_placeholder')]); !!}
```

Could someone help me get the substring of 5 digits between `://` and `.` from the decrypted value to use as a default value in my form?

Comment: Could you supply an example string?

Comment: `https://12345.test.com` and `http://12346.anotherone.de`

Comment: Yeh, not the cleanest way perhaps but it's working. Thank you @SymeonQuimby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
<?php
$a = 'https://12345.test.com';
$digits = substr($a, strpos($a, '://') + 3, 5);
```

Hope it works.

**Edit:** was missing part of the code

Answer (score 2):

As of Laravel 6+, you can use the [startsWith](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-starts-with) method.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$result = Str::startsWith('This is my name', 'This');
// true
```

As of Laravel 8+, you can pass multiple values to be tested against the string.

> If an array of possible values is passed, the startsWith method will return true if the string begins with any of the given values:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$result = Str::startsWith('This is my name', ['This', 'That', 'There']);
// true
```